# Least amount of questions to find $g^{−1}$ in direct sum table?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

I'm working in the following group theory excercise, I'll try to explain it the best way possible because was explained orally by the teacher:

> Let $G$ be a group defined by $G=(A,*)$ and $G$ has $|G|=2^{100}$ elements, so the elements of $A$ would be $A = [1,2,3, \dots 2^{100}]$. Is given the fact that the modulus is $1$.
>
> As $G$ has $2^{100}$ elements the direct sum (⊕) operation would be defined in a table of size $2^{100}$ x $2^{100}$ like the following:
>
> $$
> \begin{array}{c|lcr}
> x & \text1 & \text... & \text2^{100} \\
> \hline
> 1 & \\
> \dots & \\
> 2^{100} & 
> \end{array}
> $$
>
> Now lets suppose that a particular person owns the table and I want to find the inverse $g^{-1}$ of an element $g$ in the group. I can ask to that person as many questions as I need to find it. The only fact is that the person will charge me a cent for every question I ask.
>
> Which is the least amount of questions I can ask to find $ g ^ {- 1} $?

My reasoning is that is obvious that the desired value is lower than $|A|-1$. So I'm thinking about to decompose the table in parts in order to have something like $2log(|A|)$ but I'm not sure about this way to find the solution.

I apologize in advance if the question is not perfectly written and I would really appreciate any hint, help or correction.

Comment: What do you mean by the modulus being $1$? What does that mean?

Comment: You describe the group as using operation $*$, and then talk about direct sum $\oplus$. Is $\oplus$ meant to be the operation of the group? Is "the modulus is $1$" meant to be interpreted as "$1$ is the identity element"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any finite group $G$ of order $n$, and all $g\in G$, we know that $g^n=1$, and therefore that $g^{-1}=g^{n-1}$. So all you need to do is calculate $g^{2^{100}-1}$.

This can be achieved by successive squaring: you can query for $g^2$; then using the answer query for $g^4=g^{2^2}$; then using the answer query for $g^8=g^{2^3}$, etc. Finally, you will query for $g^{2^{99}}$ with your $99$th query.

Then, with information on $g$, $g^2$, $g^{2^3},\ldots,g^{2^{99}}$, the product of these elements is exactly$gg^2g^{2^2}\cdots g^{2^{99}} = g^M$, where
$M=2^0+2^1+2^2+\cdots + 2^{99} = \frac{2^{100}-2^0}{2-1} = 2^{100}-1$, exactly what you need.

So you can query for $gg^2$, then the product of that by $g^{2^3}$, etc. This requires $98$ more queries.

So you can definitely find the answer in no more than $99+98=197$ queries.